Git commit is still in repo after reset
I pushed a bad commit to our Gitlab repo, which contained some sensitive information. A quick google search suggested doing:
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin <branch-name> --force

I then logged onto gitlab and checked if the commit was removed from the branch, and it was, as expected. However, when I searched the repo for the specific hash of the commit I just removed, it could still be found and all the code from it could be viewed. Another internet search revealed that gitlab stores refererence to these commits in the "refs" and "packed-refs" files and in order to remove the commit entirely, I need to remove it from these files. However, when I checked both the files they did not contain the removed hash key. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Whatever key was leaked should be reset. It's already been compromised.

@JonathonReinhart that is the first thing I did when I found out. I can also solve the problem by deleting the repo and create a new one, since the project is still new and has < 10 commits. However, it would still be great to know how to do what I described in my question.

Onto the server you will continue to see the commit ref until the Gitlab housekeeping will run.
Here are the official guide with all the information: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/housekeeping.html .
As you can see, if you want, you can manually enforce it by:

On the left sidebar, select Search or go to and find your project.
Select Settings > General.
Expand Advanced.
Select Run housekeeping.


Tried that and also "Prune unreachable objects" already. Didnt help.
